# Wear OS: creating a project that contains wear OS App + wear OS Tile

Tags: android, wear-os

I am trying to create a working architecture that contains a wear os **application** and a **Tile** for the application.
After reading several times the [Android developers documentation: Tiles](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/tiles)
I'm still confused about the architecture of the project:

Is it required to create **only one wear os application** for the Tile and all the activities (that I perceive as the app activities) should be inside this app, and they will be launched solely by the Tile's graphical interface? or should I create **2 wear os apps**: *app one* for the application and *app two* for the tile, without MainActivity in the release folder (src/main)?

I know it is a general question but I think this question will be helpful for other developers in the future and I did not find any answer to this simple question after searching for hours.

Comment: You could have 1, 2, or a thousand modules. Are you asking if you need one or two *apps*? If so, then AFAIK you can have a Wear OS overlay (activities) and tiles in the same app.

Comment: @CommonsWare My mistake I meant two apps - I will fix the question

Comment: is your question answered? i just added a tile to my existing app, which also includes a watchface. with a tap on the watchface i start the app, swiping opens the tile. yes it is confusing but it works...